# корректные пути в use php

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `use` указать точный путь ?
Если сам файл php, в котором происходит это самое действие, находится в совершенно другой директории. Или дайте ссылочку, почитать. Спасибо!

Comment: В use указывается не путь. Где об этом почитать - в официальном руководстве по языку.

Comment: @u_mulder я вроде вкурсе, что там указывается. Я спросил, как указать путь до этого самого класса из нужного мне пространства имен т.к если они стоят не в одной директории то оно не работает само собой..в этом и проблема моя

Comment: Вам правильно написали что в use используется не путь, вероятно вы сами его спутали с require/include где путь как раз и используется.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov т.е я могу просто указать путь до autoload.php и все ? Правильно я понял ?

Comment: Почитайте про то, как осуществляется [автозагрузка в PHP](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/php-autoload), в Интернете полно примеров и описания на эту тему. Её суть - показать программе как найти класс по его названию. Остальные файлы, да, могут включать в себя это описание через, к примеру, autoload файл, где автозагрузка обычно описывается.

Answer (score -1):

Иcпользуй $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], который вернёт путь к корню сайта, например,

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mobile/bd.php';
```

выдаст путь, понятный PHP скрипту.

```
/home/user0106330/domains/my-site.ru/public_html/mobile/bd.php
```

Comment: В Ubuntu это не срабатывает..либо я некорректно прописываю. Вот то, как я прописывал
`use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].\ST\Socket\Chat;`
Я вроде понимаю, что это ошибка и чушь собачья, но я не понимаю, как сделать это правильно. Т.е мне нужно конкретно про директиву `use`, а не `include` или `require`